# What elements and/or substances without water are liquid at room temperature?

Tags: solutions, phase

I was thinking about liquids, and I started to wonder theses related questions:

1) Besides mercury, what elements are naturally liquid at room temperature?

2) What naturally found family of substances/mixtures that do not contain  $\ce{H2O}$ are naturally liquid at room temperature?

Comment: Strange that you didn't think of ethanol ;)  there are also lots of other organic and also inorganic liquids.

Comment: duh! of course! I totally forgot about ethanol!

Comment: liquefied gases liquid nitrogen, carbon di oxide etc, oil (a natural water hater)

Comment: [This non-exhaustive list of substances](http://figshare.com/articles/Jean_Claude_Bradley_Open_Melting_Point_Datset/1031637) contains 6179 entries which melt at or below 25°C. A few hundred of those are probably gasses at ambient conditions, a few hundred more are repeat entries for a same substance, and a large chunk of the rest is likely represented by some rather exotic compounds. Either way, goes to show there are a lot of possibilities.

Comment: (1) is readily answered by looking at most periodic tables. (2) is an extremely long list which SE is not suitable for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question is a bit broad in terms of the sheer amount of chemical compounds and mixtures that are liquid at room temperature. Examples include:

**Compounds**
Acids, bases, many hydrocarbons (e.g. hexane) and many more

**Mixtures**
Crude oil, aqua regia and many more

In terms of **elements**, there are only two that are liquid at [room temperature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_temperature) (say about 20 °C or 293 K):

- [Mercury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(element)) (as you identified).
- [Bromine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromine)

[Francium, cesium, gallium and rubidium](http://antoine.frostburg.edu/chem/senese/101/periodic/faq/liquid-elements.shtml) are close, with melting points at 300 K, 301.59 K, 303.3 K and 312.46 K respectively.

LennTech provides a list [The elements of the periodic table sorted by melting point](http://www.lenntech.com/periodic-chart-elements/melting-point.htm)

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was thinking on naturally ocurring compounds and mixtures, and also elements. Milk however, gets its liquidness because of the water in it no? It's basically water + other stuff. I guess I meant I meant mixtures that do NOT have h20 in it

Comment: The examples I gave are natural, acids, bases, hydrocarbons etc don't have water in them.